# Convert string to bash argument

Tags: linux, bash

i want to know if there is a way to do something like this

```
VAR="-o sampleoutput"
./mycommand.sh $(VAR)
```

Thank you

Edit: This question is different. When i tried to run my command withuot parenthesis too but it did not work. Here is my code

```
ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS="-J-javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar &"
./bin -Dconf=./configfile $ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS
```

This is my result

```
Bad root server path: /path/to/my/project/&
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a string, and not an array?

Comment: BTW, the *immediate* problem is that `$(VAR)` is makefile syntax, not shell syntax; in shell, `$()` is what's called command substitution, which is very different from regular variable expansion (aka "parameter expansion").

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy. Your comment saved several hours of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your () around VAR.

```
VAR="-o sampleoutput"; ./mycommand.sh $VAR
```

Comment: In general, storing multiple arguments in a string is the Wrong Thing -- lists of arguments should be stored in an _array_; that way filenames with spaces, glob characters, etc don't break your script. See also [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).